# How to generate XML with attribute data types from SQL Server table definition?

Tags: sql-server, xml, types, xsd

I need to generate XML document based on a SQL Server table. This is very simple to do with the following syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTableName
WHERE name = 'Bob'
FOR XML PATH
```

What I'm struggling with is figuring out a way to include data types for all elements automatically without having to modify XML and including additional tags manually.

I want XML attributes reflect datatypes found in table definition.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer through use of SQL Prompt auto complete feature. After typing `FOR XML RAW,` I explored other options that can be used with it.

As the result I found following two options that can be used with `FOR XML RAW`

`FOR XML RAW, XMLDATA`

`FOR XML RAW, XMLSCHEMA`

I ran the query with those options and looked at the xml document generated by the output. After I realized that this is what I been looking for, I was able to find documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510461.aspx that explained both options and how it can be used.

I slightly modified my original query,

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTableName
WHERE 1 = 0
FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA
```

By including `1=0` in where clause allowed me to only generate attribute without any data. Now all I had to do was to copy output into notepad++ and save it as .xsd file.